# CSS won't apply to elements inside innerHtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser

I am using jQuery's mobile css and js the code I provide is below

Comment: can you provide a link?

Comment: the actual page you are working on

Comment: @VictorTrot: I formatted your code but you seem to be missing `}); });` in the end of your script. I didn't add them because I don't know if that was a copy-paste error on your behalf or if that is what is causing your issue.

Comment: do you mean no jquery-mobile styles are applied?

Comment: my site is behind a very secure internal only webserver. Yes the code I provided I cut out about 90% of it because it is meaningless for this problem, I might have missed a few colons and such, but it definitely works except for this css part.

Comment: @jermal yes no jquery-mobile style stuff is applied to the data inside the innhertml, but it does apply to elements outside the script tags.

Comment: @VictorTrot: I can see this: `result_holder.innerHTML = results+' < /ul>';` but where is the opening `<ul>`? You start with `result = ''` then add `<div class="ThisIsNotStyling">....stuffff..` in a loop. Is the missing `<ul>` the problem? There seems to be  alot of code missing and replaced by `stufffff` in your question, so it is hard to be able to tell what is error and what is copy-paste issues. It's ok to only show relevant code but don't add things like `stuffff`. Make sure the code you do show is as you have it in your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to the docs:** [jquery mobile Enhancing new markup](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)

To apply jquery-mobile's styles to dynamically added content you can just run the following after your update:
`$(result_holder).trigger('create');`

See example below

```
// PRINT THE RESULT, THIS STUFF WONT STYLE
result_holder.innerHTML = results+' < /ul>';
$(result_holder).trigger('create');
```

That will tell jquery to auto-initialization all the plugins contained within the new markup